# JQuery works only for a one time

Tags: jquery

I wrote jquery function for emphasis clicked `<h4>` tag. but it only works an one time. so how I solve that problem. this is my code.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('h4').click(function(){
            var a = $('h4').attr('style');
            if(a=='font-size: 1.5em'){
                $(this).css('font-size','2.5em');
            }
            else{
                $(this).css('font-size','1.5em');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you throw a simple `console.log(a)` into the mix you'll see the problem. When you do this:

```
$(this).css('font-size', '1.5em');
```

you end up setting the style attribute to `font-size: 1.5em;`, take note of the semicolon. So your equality test fails once you've toggled back to 1.5em. I wouldn't depend on any particular format in the `style` attribute, there might be different numbers of spaces (possibly none) than you're expecting, there could be semicolons where you don't expect them, ...

You're better off doing this using a CSS class. The HTML would look like this:

```
​<h4>Header</h4>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

and the CSS something like this:

```
​h4 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
h4.emphasized {
    font-size: 2.5em;
}​
```

and finally, your JavaScript would be something nice a simple like this:

```
$('h4').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('emphasized');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2rpxa/

​